# Wireless Switch Stuck Off- HP TouchSmart tx2

Tags: wireless

The light stays red when I use the switch. First day with Ubuntu, looks nice so far but no internet. Tried a few solutions on here, but they all seem very hardware-specific. Please talk me through what to do and why it works.

My machine is an old HP TouchSmart tx2 with 12.04 64 bit. What other information would be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today.
I fixed it following the post:
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/ubuntu-63/wireless-became-disabled-how-do-i-enable-858357

Basically you run the following command from a terminal (ALT + CTRL + T) :
$ sudo rfkill unblock all

This seems to replicate what the hw switch for the wireless does when you turn it on.

After that I was able to connect to my access point without problems.